# Firebase Security Rules for .remove () method

Tags: firebase

I want to restrict .remove() method on my data - only allowing the author/creator the ability to .remove the node.  Is this possible?

I have the standard users tree and a pair of data trees geoFire and one named details.  'Details' has nodes that contain entries like timestamp and user (which matches auth.uid).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A remove in Firebase means that you're writing no/empty data to a location that currently contains data:

```
".write": "!data.exists() || newData.exists()"
```

Quick table to ensure I got all of them:

```
data.     newData.
exists()  exists()  .write
--------+---------+--------
false     false     true
false     true      true
true      false     false
true      true      true
```

Comment: Thanks Frank.  If I have 'details' with child nodes of 'name', 'age', and 'user' where user = authData.uid, do I simply put the rule just inside my "details":{ in the Security and Rules?  If I want the current user (via auth.uid) to be able to .remove(), I could say write: "auth.uid === data.child('user').val()"?

Comment: Please read the Security and Rules quickstart and guide: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/

Comment: Of course I already did.  The only like example for securing records by logged in user is for the users node/branch created automagically by Firebase auth.  What is $user?  Obviously a type of variable but how is that mapped to the users node?  This is not explained clearly.  Thanks anyway though.

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables

Comment: I saw that but how is $other mapped to anything?  Why would anyone allow a random entry in a db?  Surely they would have a parent node to file under and it seems logical to apply rules there.  I just dont have my mind around $user or $other.  If I put $otherone, $othertwo, $other3 how does firebase know to put data under that?  Does $otherone mean I have a node titled 'otherone'?  Thanks Frank for the help.

Comment: Rules that start with `$` are applied to all child nodes under there. The `$` things is just a variable name at that point. Everywhere in the rules where you use the same variable name, it effectively becomes the name of the key (as a string). You can name the `$` things anything, as long as you use the same name in the rules.

Comment: What is the use case for a variable (like $user)?  Why not simply apply whatever rule to the parent and create a child node for anything requiring more granular rules?  [Cascading:](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html) "The child rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege."

Answer (score 0):

You need to `data.exists()` rule to add in validate method otherwise it'll be failed for add a node:

i.e. note to delete :

```
db.ref('path/to/node/' + user).remove()
```

Rules:

```
".write": "auth != null",

// Delete or Add
".validate": "data.exists() || (newData.hasChildren(['child1', 'child2', '...'])" ,
```