# Firebase rules for comment on a post

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

What should be the firebase rules for comment on post which is similar to facebook.

There are two things:
first, only authenticated user can comment.
Second, only the user who has commented can delete the comment. The user who has commented his id is saved in username.
[image]

Comment: Did you try writing anything yet? If so, please update your question to show. If not, have a look at the [Firebase documentation on securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) and my recent [answer on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392059/firebase-email-saying-my-realtime-database-has-insecure-rules/51393449#51393449). To protect against deletion, see [securing for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491568/firebase-security-rules-for-remove-method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest using [Firebase Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) for writing/compiling Firebase Database Security rules. Data structure can get big and complicated. Using [Bolt language](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) you'll be able to easily write complex access and structure rules that can be re-used for other db patterns.

Your rules would look something like this:

```
path /comment/{postUid}/{commentUid} is Comment {
   read() { true }
   write() { isAuthor(this) || isAuthor(prior(this)) }
}

type Comment {
   text : String,
   username : String
}

isAuthor(value) { auth != null && value.username == auth.uid }
```

Pay attention to `isAuthor(prior(this))` call. This is the way to make sure only author can delete a comment. `prior` function returns data as it was saved before current event (create, update or delete).

After using firebase-bolt tool to compile rules to JSON format you'll get:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "comment": {
      "$postUid": {
        "$commentUid": {
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['text', 'username'])",
          "text": {
            ".validate": "newData.isString()"
          },
          "username": {
            ".validate": "newData.isString()"
          },
          "$other": {
            ".validate": "false"
          },
          ".read": "true",
          ".write": "auth != null && newData.child('username').val() == auth.uid || auth != null && data.child('username').val() == auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```